# What do 008 and voltron mean in user-agent?

Tags: support

Here is the screenshot on stackoverflow's robots.txt.

[description on robots in stackoverflow website](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt)
[image]

There are no spiders named 008 and voltron.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> There are no spiders named 008 and voltron.

That you know of, presumably. :)

I've never heard of them either, so Google to the rescue!

I'm not familiar with what happened to land these in our robots.txt, but "voltron" is described [here](http://80legs.com/the-80legs-web-crawler/):

> If you’ve come to this page, then you’re probably interested in learning more about our web crawler, identified as user-agent “voltron.”
>
> Voltron runs on the 80legs web crawling platform, which consists of many servers, which is why you may see our web crawler access your site from many different IP addresses.

And this is [008](http://www.botreports.com/user-agent/008.shtml):

> 008 is the user-agent used by 80legs, a web crawling service provider. 80legs allows its users to design and run custom web crawls. So, if 008 is crawling your website, it means that one or more 80legs users created a web crawl that went (eventually) to your website.

Comment: The reason they're in robots.txt is probably related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80legs#Technology